# Why my EC2 instance works for some time and then goes down?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 `t2.small` instance and I am using CloudFlare for DNS. I have whitelisted all CloudFlare IP's in security group.

My problem is my site works for sometime when I work in backend testing and configuring plugins but when I log out and try to reach my site it gives `522` then suddenly changes to `502` error.

When I look in the console in Volume, my burst balance shows Zero. I don't know why it keeps falling to zero when I work for sometime, but when I stop my instance for few hours and come back do some work, then again te same thing happens. where might be the problem?

I tried:

- Reinstalling wp
- Downgraded to lower version of WP
- Disabled all plugins

Comment: What type of instances are these? t2? If so, when you use up all CPU credits, performance will fall down below the baseline and you see non responsiveness.

Comment: how to keep track of cpu credits, i think they are fine but ebs burst volume becomes zero. i see there is a graph for cpu credit but i dont know how to read it.